# How do I find a number $\frac{a^4}{4}$ to be added to an odd integer $N$ to make it a Perfect Square?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

Finding the least number to be added to an integer $N$ to make it a Perfect Square is simple:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/least-number-to-be-added-to-or-subtracted-from-n-to-make-it-a-perfect-square/

But how do we proceed if we require the number to be added must be a fourth power divided by four $\frac{a^4}{4}$?

Assume $N=p_1\cdot p_2$ is a product of two primes.
How do I find a number $a$ such that $\frac{a^4}{4}+N$ is a perfect square?

An example $N=p\cdot q=7\cdot3=21$ and we find $a=2$ which produces a perfect square $21+\frac{2^4}{4}=25$ too.

Another example $N=p\cdot q=7\cdot11=77$ and we find $a=2$ which produces a Perfect Square $77+\frac{2^4}{4}=81$.

An example including larger numbers is $N=p\cdot q=5\cdot13=65$ and we find $a=8$ which produces a perfect square $65+\frac{8^4}{4}=1089$.

For a given $N$, is there a way to find such an integer $a$ (without brute force)?

Comment: correct - thank you - there is a flaw in that example. I put a better one.

Comment: Personally, I don't see that there are any helpful insights from the cited problem that help with the queried problem.  For example, if $(n=18)$, in the cited problem, you are simply examining each of the sequences $\{n, (n-1), (n-2), \cdots\}$ and $\{(n+1), (n+2), \cdots\}$ until you stumble upon a perfect square.  In the queried problem, I see no alternative to examining $\{n, [n + (1^4)/4], [n + (2^4)/4], \cdots \}$ until you **stumble** across an element in the sequence that is both a positive integer and a perfect square.

Comment: In your query, you considered whether the prime factorization of $n$ could be used to place constraints on $a$.  I question this approach.  Consider the Diophantine equation $(x + y)^2 = z^2 \implies (x + y) = z.$  I see no clear relationship between the indiviual prime factorizations of $x,y,$ and $z$.

Comment: @user2661923 The fact that $n$ is the product of two prime numbers gives *a lot* of structure to work with. See my answer for a fairly simple characterization.

Comment: @Servaes +1 to your answer : nice rebuttal to my comments.

Comment: Thank you all for these really helpful hints and for the solution. I think the question becomes even more interesting if we allow $a$ to be a rational number and if we are searching for a square in $\mathbb{Q}$ instead of a perfect square (in $\mathbb{N}$). I will investigate a bit more and formulate this extra question as a new post. Thank you all again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $n=pq$ with $p$ and $q$ prime and $p\leq q$, if $a$ is an integer such that
$$n+\frac{a^4}{4}=c^2,$$
for some positive integer $c$, then $\tfrac{a^4}{4}$ is an integer and so $a$ is even, say $a=2b$. Then also
$$pq=n=c^2-\tfrac{a^4}{4}=c^2-4b^4=(c-2b^2)(c+2b^2).$$
Then either $c-2b^2=1$ and $c+2b^2=pq$, or $c-2b^2=p$ and $c+2b^2=q$, and correspondingly
$$(2b)^2=pq-1\qquad\text{ or }\qquad (2b)^2=q-p,$$
where of course $q-p$ is the smaller of the two. So

1. If $q-p$ is a perfect square, then $a=\tfrac12\sqrt{q-p}$.
2. Else, if $pq-1$ is a perfect quare, then $a=\tfrac12\sqrt{pq-1}$.
3. Else there is no such $a$.

Comment: It seemed to me (or I still hope) that we are able to find such an $a$ in any case where $p,q$ are two distinct primes. Can we ensure this?

Comment: This answer shows that this is not the case. You've given the simplest counterexample already; if $(p,q)=(3,5)$ then you are looking for two squares differing by $n=pq=15$, where the smaller square is of the form $\tfrac{a^4}{4}$. Of course any two squares greater than $8^2=64$ differ by more than $15$, and the few smaller squares are easily checked by hand.